# Overriding specific RewriteCond in .htaccess with the one in Vhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm working with a codebase where I would like to avoid changing anything in the existing .htaccess file. This means that if there is anything in .htaccess that I need to "override" I would have to do so with vhost configuration.

having said that, is it possible to keep the .htaccess being used as is and partially override it's parts in vhost?

here's the specific example:

in .htaccess there is a rewrite condition and rewrite like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I would like these two lines to remain in the htaccess file, but somehow "ignore them" by overriding them in vhost.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can. The rules in the htaccess file get processed before anything in the vhost. Not even the mod_headers `RequestHeader set Host "www.example.com"` directive helps (as it doesn't change the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable).